# What technical restrictions might prevent MS from implementing IntelliTrace on VS 2010 64-bit?

Tags: 64-bit, visual-studio-2010, intellitrace

I found that IntelliTrace is not supported on Visual Studio 2010 64-bit version.

MS [says](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=514382) its because of technical restrictions

Can anyone shed some light on what those restrictions might be?

Thanx.

Comment: My hunch would be it having to do with issues managing the required memory usage in different threads while collecting the debug information in the background.

Comment: I shall paraphrase what they said:  "It's hard"

Comment: My hunch would be dev & test resources/time.

Comment: This problem is fixed in VS2010SP1. The answers above are correct that modify running programs need to explictly support 64 bit programs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is likely that the IntelliTrace code is written for 32 bit only right now. You cannot invoke a 32-bit library from a 64-bit executable currently in Windows. There are lots of other applications that have this problem as well. For example: Since windows explorer is 64-bit applications that contribute to the right click menu need to also be 64-bit.

This is likely the same issue here. The library was probably not ported to 64-bit yet making it not possible to call it from the new version of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the first answer. VS.NET is still a 32Bit application and to debug a 64Bit application, is surly a technical hurdle.
There were also some time constraints to push this out with the release of VS.NET 2010.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/550549/intellitrace-doesnt-work-on-x64-projects

There are some interesting links, for ex. how to debug a 64Bit App:

http://blogs.msdn.com/habibh/archive/2009/10/12/how-to-edit-code-when-debugging-a-64-bit-application.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/habibh/archive/2009/10/22/intellitrace-is-not-available-why.aspx